# What is the proper way for mail polling in Spring 3+ Tomcat apache?

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-mail, spring-3

I am working on `Spring 3` + `Apache Tomcat` based web application I need to implement mail polling in which emails will be fetched using `JMS` or any other mail server technology (like `apache camel` or `apache james`) in Web Application . I have implemented mail polling using `JMS` only, But need some more proper way like, Fetch only those emails that have been not fetched before to web application. So Please suggest me the proper way to do Mail polling in java.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand what you mean by "mail polling", but I don't know how you do that with JMS.

Assuming that what you want to do is to monitor a mailbox on a mail server for new messages, and then invoke some action when a new message arrives, you can use JavaMail to do that.  You'll need a separate thread to do the polling.  You can either connect to the server periodically and see if it has new messages, or if it's an IMAP server you can use the IMAP IDLE support in JavaMail to be notified when new mail arrives.  There's lots more details you'll need to understand, but that should get you started.  Don't forget to read the [javadocs for the various JavaMail packages](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/index.html), and the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).  You'll find lots of sample code all over the web, but especially look at the examples in the FAQ and in the sample code included in the [JavaMail download bundle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html).  The monitor.java sample program may be helpful.